# Golang Microsoft Graph Contact Import

Tags: go, microsoft-graph-api, contacts

guys. Im trying to import contacts of user from outlook using golang. What do we actually need: user logs in to his microsoft account and imports his contacts from outlook using msgraph api.

My solution:

We are embedding a microsoft login window in our frontend application (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=$clientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=$redirectUri&scope=$scope), we log in here and get authorization code, then, on backend we exchange it for users access token and using that access token we import contacts

I've registered my application in azure active directory, added needed scopes, redirect uris, created client secret. Im able to get auth code and access token, but here comes the question

The problem:

I've followed guidelines and wrote that code

```
cred, err := azidentity.NewDeviceCodeCredential(&azidentity.DeviceCodeCredentialOptions{
        TenantID: credentials.TenantID,
        ClientID: credentials.ClientID,
        UserPrompt: func(ctx context.Context, message azidentity.DeviceCodeMessage) error {
            fmt.Println(message.Message)
            return nil
        },
    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating credentials: %v\n", err)
    }

    //Contacts.Read
    authProvider, err := auth.NewAzureIdentityAuthenticationProviderWithScopes(cred, []string{"Contacts.Read"})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to init auth provider: ", err)
    }

    adapter, err := msgraphsdk.NewGraphRequestAdapter(authProvider)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to init provider: ", err)
    }

    client := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(adapter)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating client: %v\n", err)
        return nil
    }

    contacts, err := client.Me().Contacts().Get(context.Background(), nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error getting the contacts: %v\n", err)
        printOdataError(err)
    }
```

1)On the line client.Me().Contacts().Get() every time im opening authentication window, but i don't want to do that. I already have a token, and i want to use it to extract users contacts. Can i change auth process from device code credential to type where i just pass my access token?

2)Will i be able to import contacts of any user who logs in if i didn't register multi-tenant application and that user is not added to my tenant?

If you need more info about question, or our import logic, please leave a comment and i will provide additional information